# Recommend workaround for the missing environmental support in pytest/allure?

Tags: python, pytest, allure

Allure support for its environment widget for pytest is still missing in the latest version (see: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/issues/96)

I was wondering if anyone has found a workaround for this missing feature? I notice for example the environmental data is read from \allure-report\widgets\environment.json

Has anyone found success in directly writing to the environment file or found another workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write environment variables to file named `environment.properties` in simple `key=value` format:

```
browser=chrome
evn=staging
```

and put it to `path/to/allure-results/environment.properties` **before** generating a report with commandline or CI plugin

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Allure command line refuses to generate the report if the folder contains any files including environment.properties unless the --clean option is provided.

Comment: Can you please share if there were any specific errors during report generation with environment.properties in it?

Comment: Allure: Target directory C:\Allure-Test\allure-report for the report is already in use, add a '--clean' option to overwrite

Comment: the target directory is otherwise empty apart from the environment.properties file

Comment: You need to put environment.properties into allure-results directory (the one where adapter stores raw results in json format), not to target allure-report directory

Comment: so what if i want to add dynamic values for browser= and env=?

such as browser={some env variable i inject to the job} or env={parameter passed into the job}, etc

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out how to pass dynamic values to the ENV widget. And it was really easy after all.

*For people using Jenkins Allure plugin:*

We run our jobs on Windows machines (Windows Batch Command), passing some build parameters to a python test runner.

Then in post build actions were calling the **Allure Report**. Results Path is `reports/$BUILD_TAG`

$BUILD_TAG is an available environment variable (look for link under Windows batch command)

So to get your report populated with environment variables or build parameters, simply create another Windows Batch Command after you run your test with something like the following:

```
cd reports/%BUILD_TAG%
(
echo BUILD=%build%  
echo ENVIRONMENT=%env%
)>environment.properties
```

This will create an environment.properties file on the fly with your build info.

**Once your job gets to Post-build Actions (ie Allure report) it will generate all your raw json with  your environment.properties. Waa Laa!**

*Note: This is configured for Windows at the moment. In the process of getting jobs run, reports generated on Linux boxes. Change 'Windows Batch Command' to 'Execute shell' and configure for Linux commands. Should be straightforward.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just if someone need a one-liner: echo "BUILD=%build%\nENVIRONMENT=%env%\n" > results/allure-results/environment.properties